# Strange behavior for macro parts on umbraco site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, macros, umbraco

Umbraco version: umbraco v 4.0.0 (Assembly version: 1.0.3327.20280)

Asp.Net: .Net framework 2.0

Windows server 2008 with IIs7

Sometimes when viewing a page with a contained macro, the macro part of that page is completely removed, not rendered, no error no nothing only a incomplete page. Loading the same page again, it's rendered correctly. This occurs very rarely.

When investigating more deeply I found out that this is somehow connected to the recycling of the application pool in which umbraco is running in. Setting the application pool to recycle itself every 1 minute I could reproduce the behavior more often than with the default recycling time but still not consistently after every recycling.

I was never able to reproduce the error when adding the umbDebugShowTrace=true, the page always renders correctly when having it set to true.

Has anyone got a clue about what can cause this or have anyone seen this before?

Note. It just not a particular page with a macro the got this behavior, every page on the site that have a macro on it acts like this when the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your issue - so I suggest you ask this question at [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org)

There is will get a bit more visibility by the Umbraco core team who may be aware of the issue.

If you have proper steps to reproduce the bug then submit it to the [umbraco codeplex site](http://www.codeplex.com/umbraco) so that it can get fixed.

T